# Owncloud - Access files locally on a network instead of sync client

Tags: nas, owncloud, qnap

I have a typical use case that I think a lot of people would have a similar situation but I cannot find a solution on the internet or even a discussion about it.

I have owncloud installed on a QNAP NAS in an office environment. This NAS has 36TB of usable space on RAID 5. I have multiple users that work from home so the owncloud sync client is great for those users but I have a user that is on the local network (at the office with the QNAP) that needs direct access to the files from his Mac (video editing).

I ssh into the QNAP and found the raid mount and then found the owncloud raw files. I have mounted this folder on his mac to access the owncloud files directly (which is fine cause this user is the VP so I'm not worried about folder/user permissions)

My question is, this seems terrible all around but it's the only thing I can think of. I don't want him to have to use the sync client cause these files are rather large AND since he's messing around with a lot of video files, it would require his local mac workstation to have 10TB+ of local storage just for him to do his daily tasks.

Another question, does owncloud monitor files/folders automatically if you are modifying them outside of the sync client?

PLEASE point me in the right direction, this situation seems like it would be common. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just try with a test file?
From [this page](https://doc.owncloud.com/android/next/faq.html) about the android app: _Detect and Upload Changes From Local File System: Local changes get recognized and uploaded when you add files inside the app, or a 3rd party app sends a file to the ownCloud app, or a 3rd party app adds/edits files via the document provider._ Often behavior of app and server are similar.

Comment: Have you looked into using [WebDAV](https://doc.owncloud.com/webui/next/classic_ui/files/access_webdav.html)?

Comment: What does access/messing around mean - read or write? If it's writing, you should definitely use the sync client, as most applications assume they're writing to a local disk and not the network, which can be unstable and cause errors.

Comment: 1. _Starting with version 3.2, the ownCloud Desktop app is fully compatible with Infinite Scale as well as the recent ownCloud Server._ [From here](https://doc.owncloud.com/docs/next/).

2. Infinite Scale *Features **NFS (POSIX)** “ocis” driver (“decomposedfs”), the default filesystem for Infinite Scale*. 

3.-> So it seems that at least via Infinite Scale and Mac you should have a filesystem aware of changes when NFS mounted and integrated with all the app and server...

Answer (score 0):

Here [the manual](https://doc.owncloud.com/server/10.12/admin_manual/qnap/) for ownCloud on QNAP.
Since QNAP is a cool and expensive stuff, I think the right place to ask is their [(virtual) support desk](https://service.qnap.com/).

You may have, however, some solutions/workarounds (I prefer the #3):

1. Empirical approach

   - Try adding a file via scp (ssh) or via the NFS mounted directory and check on other clients whether it appears or not.
   - Try substituting a file meanwhile a slow client is downloading. The upload has to be faster than (and has to end before) the client download or page refreshing. Check what happens.
   - Try to add/delete/modify a file from app/webpage and see when it is visible on NFS.
2. **Add desktop app** (running in background) and edit file directly via **NFS**. Check the results (in hopes that the app will only perform the *atomic* actions related to adding/deleting/modifying a file needed by the server).
3. Mount **NFS with read-only** (no write) privileges. So your *privileged* user can read them fast but it is forced to upload modifications only via app. This can be with or without desktop app.
4. If your QNAP has 2 different network interfaces, reserve one for this *special user* only and put all others on the second interface. This can avoid some bottlenecks if the separate interfaces are not yet dedicated to different services.

#### TL; DR

From the [android app docs](https://doc.owncloud.com/android/next/faq.html) we can read:

> ##### Detect and Upload Changes From Local File System
>
> Local changes get recognized and uploaded when you add files inside the app, or a 3rd party app sends a file to the ownCloud app, or a 3rd party app adds/edits files via the document provider.

This does not solve our doubts, because it didn't clarify whether *Local changes get recognized* are limited to those made in the specified ways or not.

Reading [more](https://doc.owncloud.com/ocis/next/) it seems that you should be able to find workarounds:

1. > Starting with version 3.2, the ownCloud Desktop app is fully compatible with Infinite Scale as well as the recent ownCloud Server.
2. > ###### Infinite Scale Features
   >
   > ```
   > Storage  | Local (POSIX)  | “ocis” driver (“decomposedfs”), the default filesystem for Infinite Scale
   >          | NFS (POSIX)    | “ocis” driver (“decomposedfs”), the default filesystem for Infinite Scale
   > ```